# Reentrantlock works fine in Java but causes IllegalMonitorException in Scala

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency, reentrantlock

I would like to migrate a Java function

```
protected static final Lock LOCK = new ReentrantLock();
public double calculate(...){
    try {
        LOCK.tryLock(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ...
    }finally{
        LOCK.unlock()
    }
}
```

The same function in Scala:

```
protected final def LOCK = new ReentrantLock
def calculate(...): double = {
    try{
        LOCK.tryLock(20, TimeUnit.Seconds)
        ...
    }finally{
        LOCK.unlock()
    }
}
```

The `LOCK.unlock()` is always causing a IllegalMonitorStateException. I dont see any reason why this is happpening.

Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Is your `calculate` method in a class/trait by any chance? Because in the java version `Lock` is static, so translating that in scala would mean putting it in an object, **not** in the class/trait where `calculate`  is defined.

Comment: Plus, and this is probably the reason of the error, you are  defining `LOCK ` as a `def` but it should really be a `val`. Otherwise, you are recreating a new lock each time you reference `LOCK` effectively rendering the lock useless.

Comment: Common practice is to acquire a lock before try, not inside.

Comment: the calculate method is in a abstract class. Is is maybe because an other thread is trying to unlock this LOCK ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely make `LOCK` a `val` instead of a `def`.
As it stands, you are recreating a new instance of `ReetrantLock` every time you. Effectively what you are doing is this:

```
try {
    // Useless as we are creating a new lock
    (new ReentrantLock).tryLock(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).tryLock(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).tryLock(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    ...
}finally{
    // Useless too, and will actually throw because we unlock a fresh (thus unlocked) lock
    (new ReentrantLock).unlock()
}
```

It is obviously bound to fail.

You should do something like:

```
object MyClass {
  private val LOCK = new ReentrantLock
}
class MyClass {
  def calculate(...): double = {
      try{
          LOCK.tryLock(20, TimeUnit.Seconds)
          ...
      }finally{
          LOCK.unlock()
      }
  }
}
```

Which is the direct translation to scala of your original java code.

Finally, in his (now deleted) answer Jon Skeet rightly suggests:

> You should only unlock the lock if you managed to acquire it - and the
>   conventional pattern is to put the lock/tryLock call before the try.
>   (It doesn't matter with tryLock(), but it does matter for lock(), so
>   we might as well be consistent.)

Which gives:

```
object MyClass {
  private val LOCK = new ReentrantLock
}
class MyClass {
  def calculate(...): double = {
      val gotLock = LOCK.tryLock(20, TimeUnit.Seconds)
      try {
          ...
      } finally {
        if (gotLock) {
          LOCK.unlock()
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: LOCK cannot be resolved in 'MyClass'. Seems that I am not missing something